# Pattern Matching List[Any] with nested lists Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

How can i achieve this? Where `xs` is a List[Any].

```
def flatten(xs: List[Any]): List[Any] = {
    xs match {
        case x: List[Any] :: t => flatten(x) ::: flatten(t)
        case x :: t => x :: flatten(t)
        case Nil => Nil
    }
}
```

The first case does not work properly. For some reason I cannot give a type to the head of the list `x`.

Comment: what exactly you want to do? `case x: List[Any]` does not match for type constructor.
and head of list will not be list. What is the type signature of `foo`?

Comment: If you have a **List[Any]** you have a code smell. And if such list is nested, it probably means a poorly designed data. - It may be better to explain the meta problem you are trying to solve, so we could give you better advice.

Comment: Ok. I editted to show the actual problem I am trying to solve. I know there is a flatten function implemented in scala already but I am trying to implement my own

Comment: Why do you need a flatten of arbitrary deep over a list any?

Answer (score 1):

As @Luis mentioned, this is really bad idea to use List[Any] but you still want to write `flatten`, then using reflection you can do like this:

```scala
val xs: List[Any] = List(List(1, 2), 3, 4)

def flatten(xs: List[Any]): List[Any] = {
  xs match {
    case x :: t if x.isInstanceOf[List[_]] => flatten(x.asInstanceOf[List[Any]]) ::: flatten(t)
    case x :: t                         => x :: flatten(t)
    case Nil                            => Nil
  }
}

println(flatten(xs)) // List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```